# EGL error when trying to run mapsActivity on Android emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, opengl-es, android-emulator

I'm trying to launch the default Google Maps Activity on an Android emulator API 25 with Google APIs and I'm getting the following error:

```
Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-15 11:30:25.043 3888-3937/dk.pawliux.app.mapstest D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
04-15 11:30:25.096 3888-3933/dk.pawliux.app.mapstest E/EGL_emulation: rcCreateContext returned 0
04-15 11:30:25.097 3888-3933/dk.pawliux.app.mapstest E/EGL_emulation: tid 3933: eglCreateContext(1284): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
04-15 11:30:25.097 3888-3933/dk.pawliux.app.mapstest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 194
                                                                       Process: dk.pawliux.app.mapstest, PID: 3888
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed: 12291
                                                                           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bi.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:834)
                                                                           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bj.f(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:20825)
                                                                           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bj.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:881)
```

As I can see on a merged manifest, there's written:

`<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>`

Does it mean that I'm trying to launch an app that uses higher EGL than my emulator/graphics card support? I am using Intel HD Graphics 3000 with HAXM enabled.

As have tried to launch on many other APIs with Google APIs and get still the same. Even though my test app doesn't launch but the integrated Google Maps application launches and works without any problem on the emulator.

Is there a way to workaround my problem?

Application is working on a real device.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like I have found the solution to my own problem. I'm posting it here in case anyone else meets the same problem.

When creating a new Emulator one can choose some options in Emulated performance. It may be `Automatic`, `Hardware GLES` or `Software GLES`. In my case `Software GLES 2.0` did the magic. The maps are working a little bit slower but fast enough to have patience to try my app out.

Here's the picture of place where to choose `Emulation for Graphics`

[image: Graphics emulation options]

I suppose my graphics card has issues with emulators.

Comment: On my Windows 10 dev laptop, the emulators have recently been running in "Compatibility Renderer" mode because my Intel Graphics 4600 or Nvidia GeForce GTX 960M have been freezing up the emulator. So even selecting `Software GLES 2.0` causes `RuntimeException: createContext at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector`

Comment: TLDR: Google's emulators - on my laptop - are not useful... I guess back to Genymotion

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to fix this is by going to the settings of the emulator itself and then changing the OpenGL ES render option, in my case changing Desktop native OpenGL fixed the problem.

Please check the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot here]